# InfluxQL : Influx DB conversion of a field from String to integer

Tags: influxdb

I am new to InfluxDB.
I have filled the influx measurements with time series data

I have the following measurement point

```
time,host,interface,value
2/11/2019 12:03:08 AM,XYZ_test ,gigabitethernet8/43,"292724"
```

the value is in the form of String I need to use InfluxQL to convert the column to Integer or float , how to do it ?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You would need to write to InfluxQL a number type. Did you use telegraf to collect these metrics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this you should be able to cast the values from float to integer.

`SELECT column_name::integer FROM table_name`

You can refer to the InfluxDB docs here,

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#cast-float-field-values-to-integers

**Edit:** 
But, however, there is no support for converting a string to an integer.

Comment: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#cast-float-field-values-to-integers from the link it is clear that the float can be converted to integerts and integers to floats , but this doesnt allow type casting from string to float or to integer.